# How to open a terminal and go to my home directory

Tags: login

I have installed `Ubuntu 13.04`. When I open the terminal using `ctrl+alt+t`, it goes to `ubuntu@ubuntu`. I want it to go to my home directory. Also when I reboot it does not ask for my login it shows the install option.

Comment: you can ls, to check its home directory or not, its seems that you have choose Ubuntu as username & hostname Ubuntu as well..

Comment: Are you sure you are not still booting up from the live DVD/USB that you made?

Comment: May be ......up vote

Comment: Yes you most probably still having DVD or USB attached to your computer and computer is booting everytime from there instead of your Hard Drive OR you just isn't installed Ubuntu 13.04 yet.

Comment: Yes I had USB still in the laptop. I removed USB, then hit esc during boot up and set option to boot from hard drive disk. Now it won't OS won't even boot up hangs. I tried with 11.04 same results. Please help

Answer (score 4):

If when you reboot it does not ask for your login, but instead it shows the install option, that probably means that you forgot to remove the CD, DVD or USB flash drive that you used to install Ubuntu with. That would also explain why you got the `ubuntu@ubuntu` when you opened the terminal since in the Ubuntu live CD/DVD/USB, `ubuntu` is the default username and it's also the name of the machine that you're working on.

After you have installed Ubuntu, the terminal opens by default to the `/home/USERNAME` directory where USERNAME is the username you use to login to Ubuntu. The shortcut for `/home/USERNAME` in the terminal is the <kbd>**~**</kbd> (tilde) character.

Comment: Yes I had USB still in the laptop. I removed USB, then hit esc during boot up and set option to boot from hard drive disk. Now it won't OS won't even boot up hangs. I tried with 11.04 same results. Please help

Comment: Really, the best thing you can do right now since you've got a _new_ problem is to ask a separate new question. Make sure to include the model of your computer, and also the amount of RAM memory if you know it, since it's important. Leave out the part about Ubuntu 11.04. Ubuntu 11.04 is End Of Life, so you can't install it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You should just reinstall the OS. Just go to one of these links to download [Ubuntu 16.04.1 (Xenial Xerus)](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.1/) disk images:

- [AMD64](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.1/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso)
- [i386](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.1/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-i386.iso)

If you are still having problems, then I am not sure what it is. If you need to return to your home directory with the terminal just use

```
$ cd /home/$USERNAME
```